# TestCafe hangs while redirecting URL to homepage

Tags: redirect, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

I have been using TestCafe for a while and did not face any redirect issue until now. When my tests are launched the website checks if I'm logged in or not and if not it redirects to the login page. This is where TestCafe started to hang (keeps loading until timeout) while redirecting to the login page and **only in concurrent browsers** (3 in my case). If I run my tests in a single browser (not concurrent) then I don't see any issue. I have `skipJsErrors` flag turned on as well as I read somewhere that it could be because of that too but that didn't resolve my issue.

I don't know how this issue started as no new updates from TestCafe released recently and no changes were done in my web application too. To fix this I changed my `${URL}` to `${URL/login}` and it started working for a day then suddenly started giving the same problem then I again changed back to my original `${URL}` which fixed the problem again.

Any idea on how to fix this and what is the exact problem here?

Answer (score 2):

Likely, there are some problems with the tested site. If you can create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that illustrates the TestCafe problem, please create an [issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) in the TestCafe repository on Github.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't create an example as I am not able to reproduce the problem in that